# stuck after imagemagick convert command

Tags: imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

I use mac os mavericks and now need to use convert command.
It worked before, however now it just stuck when I type the following command:

```
echo test|convert -font Monaco label:@- name.jpg
```

I have to ctrl-c it.
Could smbd help how to get it back working or how can I do the same?
(I need to convert text into jpg image)

I remember that I installed some applications after last time it worked, however I do not remember exactly which apps.

Comment: Mmmm... odd that you must Control-C that! Try removing the "-font Monaco" to rule out a missing font first. Then try removing the "echo test|" and changing to simply running "convert label:'test' name.jpg" to rule out the "echo" and pipe.

Comment: Yes, I had to install readline to make it working. Now it works. Thanks.

Comment: I'll put my suggestion as an answer for all to see - maybe you could accept it then, please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may need to install `readline` to do that.